# How to use chrome profile when using browserInDocker with WebDriverManager?

Tags: java, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I'm using webdrivermanager with browserInDocker() for my test automation framework. So far it works great. But now I have trouble trying to use a chrome profile.
Usually, when I use selenium webdriver, I simply can set a ChromeOption and it works.

How can I use it with browserInDocker()?

I tried the following code:

```
public void setupBrowserInDockerWithProfile() {
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=/home/seluser/.config/google-chrome/Default");
   driver = WebDriverManager
             .chromedriver()
             .capabilities(options)
             .browserInDocker()
             .dockerVolumes("/var/lib/docker/volumes/chromeprofile/_data:/home/seluser/.config/google-chrome/Default")
             .create();
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.get(APP_URL);
}
```

I tried it with and without a docker volume, but I'm not even sure if I use it right. I'm searching for days now, but could't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the argument `--user-data-dir=/home/seluser/.config/google-chrome/Default`. As explained in the [doc](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#browsers-in-docker), WebDriverManager uses the Aerokube's Docker images. That path is available in the docker-images, but not in Aerokube's. You can drop that argument or change it to the following:

```
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=/home/selenium/.config/google-chrome/Default");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried it out, but the result is the same. If I try to use the docker volume, the setup breaks, and I got a NullPointerException. If I comment out the line .dockerVolumes() tests are running, but still without my chrome profile.